# Chrome Extension: Go to site when extension icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, http-redirect

I am new to making Chrome Extensions, and I wanted to make an extension that would open up a site (like [www.tamoghnak.tk](https://www.tamoghnak.tk) in a new tab. I have no clue on what to do.
How would I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called a ["browser action"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/) (or "page action" if you only want the icon to be visible on certain websites).

You can declare a browser action, that is specify which icons to display, in your extension's manifest like so :

```json
{
  "name": "My extension"
   ...
   "action": {
     // Declare icons for multiple sizes (optional)
     "default_icon": {
       "16": "images/icon16.png",
       "24": "images/icon24.png",
       "32": "images/icon32.png"
     },
     // Icon tooltip text (optional)
     "default_title": "My Extension",
   },
   "background": {
     "scripts": ["background.js"],
     "persistent": false
   },
   ...
}
```

I also declared a ["background script"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages/) in the manifest. In `background.js` you can add a click listener that will open your URL on click like this :

```js
const extensionIconClickListener = () => {
   chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://your-url.com' });
};
        
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(extensionIconClickListener);
```

Comment: It says there is an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClicked' of undefined" Please help.

Comment: Are you using a manifest V2 ? It is only available for V2

Comment: Yes, I am using V2

Comment: Then I suggest that you share your code or a sample repo to understand what is going on. You may also find solutions to that specific question elsewhere on stackoverflow

Comment: @TamoghnaK13 hi, have you managed to find a way to achieve what you wanted ?